# Como criar caixa de texto editável por cima de uma imagem (ex.: como no PowerPoint)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, css, node.js, ejs

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um slide show como o Power Point, só que no ambiente do browser com Node.js (ejs, sequelize, etc.)

Consegui criar a parte de inclusão da imagem e do texto mandando pro BD e puxando as informações de lá, contudo, o texto é digitado num *input* separado, e eu gostaria que ele fosse digitado, direto na imagem (do mesmo jeito de quando se escreve dentro de um slide no Power Point), para que a experiência do usuário seja melhor.

Também gostaria de saber como posso fazer essa caixa de texto ser movida dentro da imagem, quando o usuário arrastar a seta do mouse.

Segue parte do código:

```
<figure>
            <span class="trs next"></span>
            <span class="trs prev"></span>             

            <!-- Espaço do slide-->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row" id="slider">
                    <% dataimg.forEach(slide => { %>                    
                        <a href="#" class="trs">
                            <img name="slide" src="img/<%=slide.chooseimg %>" 
                            width="100%" height="600">  
                            <div class="text"><%= slide.text %></div>                              
                        </a>       

                    <% }) %> 
                </div>
            </div>
           <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Segue também a parte do form em que estou incluindo a imagem e a legenda (mas que gostaria de que fosse direto na imagem)

```
<div class="container-fluid cards">
            <div class="row">
        <!-- Card de inclusão de imagem e texto-->
        <form method="POST" action="/savedata">
            <div class="card  mx-md-3 my-md-2" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" id="img_preview" src="" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="text-center my-3">                                   
                    <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()" class="col-md-6" id="img_input" name="chooseimg">

            </div>

            <!-- Inclusão de texto-->
            <div class="card-body">                
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Texto</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </p> 
            <!-- Botão inclua-->
                    <div class="text-center mt-md-1">
                        <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4" id="btn+">Inclua</button> 
                    </div> 
                </form>                     
            </div>
          </div>
```

Não consegui encontrar nada parecido no Google, porque a busca sempre retorna como incluir essa caixa de texto direto no código (pelo programador) e não pelo usuário final. É isso, desde já. Agradeço!